# Material design backwards compatibility for pre L release Android

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop

How can I include the new 'Material Design' in versions of Android before the L release?

Comment: I guess you have to wait until they release some updated versions of the **support library**

Answer (score 0):

Currently Material Design is only available as a part of Android L Preview. **Since it is only a preview to developers, it is not backward compatible**. Wait for a final release for the backward compatibility across various SDKs

Comment: Have any documentation stating this?  I haven't heard of any official support for back compat